# Incomplete rendering

Tags: rendering, hardware

Blender 2.76 is rendering only a portion of the scene.

[image: Incomplete render in render view.]

OS: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS; kernel: 4.4.0-51-generic; video card: Nvidia GeForce 6600 GT; Nouveau driver.

No alterations to Blender's default configuration were made: I simply started Blender up and clicked on the render button so it would render the default cube scene. Although the on-screen rendering was incomplete, the rendered scene was complete as a saved image.

I will try the Nvidia driver with it; however, I have been unable to get an efficiently usable desktop environment using that driver (incorrect resolution with screen badly offset).

Comment: Please provide more information so we can diagnose the problem, like scene properties and render settings. Also check if you have *Render Border* enabled

Comment: I had a similar problem that was related to a diver issue where only the first few tiles were being drawn on the screen but the actual render written to disk (and passed on to the compositor) was fine. Does the output written out to disk match what you're seeing on screen?

Comment: Don't use the Nouveau driver, use the proprietary Nvidia drivers.

Comment: I have installed the Nvidia driver, version 304.132. When run as a normal user, a window border is created for it but it immediately then segfaults; when run as root, it runs okay, apart from a 'connect failed' error (as per normal user error below)) and renders the default scene completely.

Normal user error:
`connect failed: No such file or directory
Ignoring Xlib error: error code 2 request code 155
Writing: /tmp/blender.crash.txt
Segmentation fault`

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the file for different renderings before? I had that issue when using one file for rendering several images one after another. Try opening a new file, then append all stuff from the current file into a new one.

On the screenshot I see that you are using Blender 2.76. I had that trouble also with 2.76, but with 2.78 it did not happen until now.